# How to change Matplotlib barchart image size

Tags: python

Im having some issues with my Matplotlib barchart, my barchart's size is zoomed in for some reason and im not sure why. This is what it currently looks like
[image: Bar Chart]

A lot of the values cannot be seen, is there a way I can zoom out or maybe resize the image upon creating the barchart? My Code

```
    Bar_Year = ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5','Year 10','Year 20','Year 30']
    Bar_Rent = [Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, Year5, Year10, Year20, Year30]
    Bar_Color = ['#003049','#D62828','#F77F00','#000000','#2A1A1F','#4D6A6D','#222E50','#439A86']
    #Creating Bar Chart with MatPlotLib
    plt.clf()
    plt.bar(Bar_Year, Bar_Rent, color=Bar_Color)
    plt.title('Rent Growth')
    plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('Future Figures')
    #Creating the Image Name
    image_name2 = random.randint(5000, 10000)
    image_name2 = str(image_name2) + '.png'
    #Saving the Bar Chart
    fig.savefig(image_name2, dpi=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import random
#figure(figsize=(2,10), dpi=80)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 11)) # you can edit this line accordingly 

Bar_Year = ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5','Year 10','Year 20','Year 30']
Bar_Rent = ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5','Year 10','Year 20','Year 30']
Bar_Color = ['#003049','#D62828','#F77F00','#000000','#2A1A1F','#4D6A6D','#222E50','#439A86']
#Creating Bar Chart with MatPlotLib
plt.clf()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.bar(Bar_Year, Bar_Rent, color=Bar_Color)
plt.title('Rent Growth')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('Future Figures')
#Creating the Image Name
image_name2 = random.randint(5000, 10000)
print(image_name2)
image_name2 = str(image_name2) + '.png'
#Saving the Bar Chart
fig.savefig(image_name2, dpi=100 )
```

Comment: Thank you and I just tried this and it doesn't seem to work, and when I put the line at the beginning of the bar chart creation the image just disappears. Is there somewhere special I need to put it?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Give it a thumbs up if it works.